# Hook action to WP_User->add_cap() and WP_User->remove_cap()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve the following:

- Each time "WP_User->add_cap()" or "WP_User->remove_cap()" is performed (by any entity: plugin, custom code, core WP process, etc...)
- Add a custom action to it

Something like:

```
add_action( 'add_cap', 'MyFunction' );
function MyFunction() {
     // Add field to the user meta data
}
```

Is this possible at all?

Any help is appreciated.

WP_User->add_cap() doc: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_cap/

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think that is possible.

When you see the code in wordpress track. (see here : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-role.php#L58)

```php
50          /**
51           * Assign role a capability.
52           *
53           * @since 2.0.0
54           *
55           * @param string $cap   Capability name.
56           * @param bool   $grant Whether role has capability privilege.
57           */
58          public function add_cap( $cap, $grant = true ) {
59                  $this->capabilities[ $cap ] = $grant;
60                  wp_roles()->add_cap( $this->name, $cap, $grant );
61          }
```

The add_cap method used is this.

```php
/**
 * Add capability to role.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param string $role  Role name.
 * @param string $cap   Capability name.
 * @param bool   $grant Optional. Whether role is capable of performing capability.
 *                      Default true.
 */
public function add_cap( $role, $cap, $grant = true ) {
    if ( ! isset( $this->roles[ $role ] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $this->roles[ $role ]['capabilities'][ $cap ] = $grant;
    if ( $this->use_db ) {
        update_option( $this->role_key, $this->roles );
    }
}
```

I cannot see any kind of hook here which you can use.

Comment: Yeah. It looks like you're referring to "adding capabilities" to "roles". I'm actually talking about "adding capabilities" to individual users. See here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php#L683

Comment: Oh okay, seems like it also doesn't provide any kind of hook.

Comment: Ok, thanks @bhanu, it's useful to know that.